# Understanding "Size" Column in RESTORE FILELISTONLY for Differential and Log Backups in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, restore

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the "Size" column in the output of the `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` command in SQL Server when it's used with differential and log backups.

For full backups, I understand that the "Size" value represents the file size on disk after restoring the backup. However, I'm not sure how to interpret this value for differential and log backups. Does it mean that after restoring the backup, the file on disk will increase by this size?

Here's an example of a `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` result for a differential backup:

```
+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+----------+
| LogicalName | PhysicalName  | Type | FileGroupName | Size     |
+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+----------+
| dx          | F:\dx.mdf     | D    | PRIMARY       | 83788608 |
| dx_log      | F:\dx_log.ldf | L    | NULL          | 46385562 |
+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+----------+
```

And here's an example for a log backup:

```
+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+----------+
| LogicalName | PhysicalName  | Type | FileGroupName | Size     |
+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+----------+
| dx          | F:\dx.mdf     | D    | PRIMARY       | 19386301 |
| dx_log      | F:\dx_log.ldf | L    | NULL          |  3327087 |
+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+----------+
```

Can someone help me understand the "Size" column in these scenarios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Size column reflect the size of the database file at the time that backup was produced (be it mdf, ndf or ldf). It has the same meaning for the different backup types. For instance, I did a full backup, and subsequent diff and log backups (with modifications of data in between). The size column remained the same for all those backups.

My guess if that the database file was changed between those backup occasion, assuming that they are for the same database. If, for instance, the log backup was done after the differential backup, then a shrink was performed between those backup occasions.